# improper integral, fourier transform

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

calculating the fourier transform of

$$f(t)=e^{-|t|}$$

yields

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{(1-ix)t}\,dt + \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(1+ix)t}\,dt = \left[ \frac{e^{(1-ix)t}}{(1-ix)} \right]_{-\infty}^{0} + \left[ \frac{e^{-(1+ix)t}}{-(1+ix)} \right]_{0}^{+\infty}.$$

i know that

$$\lim_{t \to -\infty} e^{t}=0,\quad \lim_{t \to 0} e^{t}=1,\quad \lim_{t \to +\infty} e^{t}=+\infty.$$

however, i am rather unfamiliar with limits of functions taking complex arguments. do the limits

$$\lim_{t \to -\infty}e^{it},\quad \lim_{t \to +\infty}e^{it}$$

exist? how can i proceed in the above expression?

Comment: Given a fraction in which the numerator has constant magnitude and the denominator goes to infinity, I wouldn't worry about a limit of the numerator.

Comment: To answer your specific query, $\lim_{t→± ∞}e^{it}$ doesn't exist; consider the subsequence $e^{i k\pi},\ k=0,1,2,3,\dots$ which takes the values $±1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{-(1 + ix)t}}{-(1 + ix)}  
$$
exists and is $0$ due to the decay of $e^{-(1+ix)t}$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ (and 
similarly for the other endpoint). To see this, just note that if we take
absolute values we have 
\begin{align*}
\left | \frac{e^{-(1+ix)t}}{-(1 + ix)} \right |
&= \frac{|e^{-(1+ix)t}|}{|1 + ix|} \\
&= \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} \\
&\leq e^{-t}.
\end{align*}
Thus, by the squeeze theorem, we have 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \left | \frac{e^{-(1+ix)t}}{-(1 + ix)} \right |
= 0,
\end{align*}
which is equivalent to 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{-(1+ix)t}}{-(1 + ix)}
= 0.
\end{align*}